# Emacsでバックグラウンドに画像を表示させる方法

Tags: emacs

Emacsにてバックグラウンドに画像を表示させる方法を探しています。

つまり壁紙のように、現在のバッファやウィンドウ、フレームに関係なく後ろに何らかの画像を表示させたいというものです。

現在の試行錯誤としては、`(set-frame-parameter nil 'alpha 85)`というコードをevalし、作業用のフレームの後ろに画像を表示させたフレームを作っています。
この方法では全てEmacsLispを使って行なえるのですが、Emacs自身の機能等でもっと楽に行なえたり、もっと良い方法が無いでしょうか？

勿論、多少意図道理でない(ウィンドウによって画像が違う等)方法もあれば嬉しいです。
書いている言語のチートシートを表示させたいと思っています。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

通常の GNU Emacs では不可能です。が、Emacs-BGEX patch をあててビルドすると、ご質問の通りではありませんが Emacs にバッファ単位で壁紙画像を指定出来るようになります。

X 上でないと動きません（MacやWin用のGUIでは不可能）ですが、
MacやWindowsでもXは動かせるので一応Mac,Windows,*nix全対応と言えます。

http://umiushi.org/~wac/bgex/

また、詳しくは知らないのですが、 Emacs のフォークである XEmacs でもそのような機能が標準であります。

http://www.xemacs.org/

XEmacs はもう古いのが難点でしょうか。